# How to build reusable Stepper on Android?

Tags: android, material-design

I was reviewing the Material Stepper guide: 
https://material.io/guidelines/components/steppers.html

I want to know the best way of implement this component. I know that I should use Fragments and implement a ViewPager. I want a complete answer about how to design the software and develop the Stepper, what modules and Android components should create/use.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439423/material-design-stepper-control

Comment: Vertical or linear?

Comment: Vertical steppers