# Step Viewer with two text view

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Step viewer with two text view]

I want to step up my xml with step view and textview . I don't think adding a proper step view is recommended as it will just for show no updation will be done, can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: try with this one

Comment: https://github.com/badoualy/stepper-indicator

Comment: i don't want any animation so there is no use of adding dependencies

Comment: share me your design

Comment: you can use image and change when you want

Comment: adding image wont allow text to add in front of it specifically in front of dots

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439423/material-design-stepper-control